# How can I use the SQLite DB so that it doesn't grow unecessarily

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a service that creates records in the apps' SQLite DB, processes data, and removes records from the SQLite DB.

I've found that the SQLite DB has grown over time (maybe a week) eventhough the amount of records in it has remained fairly constant.

**Question**
What is the best practice to add and remove records without growing the database ?

To insert a record I use:
`result = mDB.insert(table, null, kvpairs);`

To remove a record I use:
`result = mDB.delete(table, where, null);`

**reference**

[Android SQLiteDatabase insert](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29)

[Android SQLiteDatabase delete](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#delete%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29)

Comment: if you mind I'm curious to see the rate of growth; can you add the size of the DB file before it grows, after it grows significantly, the number of records in each case, and even better, run `VACUUM` as CL mentions, and post the resulting size of the DB.

Comment: When VACUUM run it create a copy of DB , so while executing VACUUM it size grow up insignificantly..At that time APP performance get down. So is there any other option to reduce DB size.??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Free pages in the database will be reused, so the growth will not be unlimited.

You could try updating records in place, but this will not help if you cannot map old to new records or if some values change their size.

Try running [VACUUM](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html) regularly, and/or enabling [PRAGMA auto_vacuum](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_auto_vacuum).